# xbindkeys can't capture extra mouse buttons on KDE 5

Tags: mouse, kde, ubuntu-studio, xbindkeys

I am trying to use my extra mouse buttons for something useful.

In Xfce it worked flawlessly, but in KDE it seems xbindkeys can't capture the mouse buttons.

xbindkeys -n shows a warning there is a conflict and xbindkeys -k doesn't show anything when pressing any buttons on the mouse:

```
*** Warning ***
Please verify that there is not another program running
which captures one of the keys captured by xbindkeys.
It seems that there is a conflict, and xbindkeys can't
grab all the keys defined in its configuration file.
```

xev can detect the extra buttons been pressed:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967280 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I have searched for help on this, but all the answers are too old and don't work anymore.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: Ubuntu Studio 20.10

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem!

kglobalaccel5 was conflicting with xbindkeys.
I was able to run both, but I had to disable all custom shortcuts. They are on System Settings->Shortcuts->Custom Shortcuts.

The strange is there was no shortcut using the extra mouse buttons. My theory is the gestures support was not well implemented.